# App that decrypts and displays an AES-encrypted file

Tags: android, security, encryption

I'm looking for a lightweight Android app, that:

1. lets the user choose a file
2. asks for the password
3. opens this file and displays the decrypted content in a textarea (scrollable)

However, the app:

5. should **not** write the decrypted file on disk (internal or external microSD card) but only displays it,
6. it should **not** require network access at all.

Lastly:

7. the app should use a standardized AES encryption (the input file will be encrypted on PC / Windows, and it has to be read on the phone).
8. the app should be able to deal with > 300 kB files (so it seems that opening a file in a text editor, *Select All*, *Copy*, go in encrypt/decrypt app, *Paste* won't work, because I noticed that clipboard doesn't seem to support *Copy/paste* with > 300 kB files).

Also I've looked at [this list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_textencrypt#group_470) of apps, and none of them really meets all these criteria.

I'm pretty sure it will be difficult to find an app that meets all criteria, so if there is an open-source app that does most of them, I'll be happy to fork it.

---

Application: Sometimes I have a big text file (written on PC / Windows), and I'd like to read it (read-only) on my phone.

Comment: Another one of my lists is about [Encryption of Files and Folders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_encrypt) – maybe you're luckier with that?

Comment: No luck there sadly @Izzy, nearly all apps have > 2 permissions required, and I tried those with only 2 permissions, but they are not exactly what is needed.

Comment: I've tried to complete those lists, but sadly found no more candidates either. Hopefully someone comes up with what we've missed. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all you've tried already @Izzy. I'll be happy to write such an open-source app, as soon as [I find a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47167769/1422096) that allows to write an Android app from my text editor without having to put my hands in a (dirty ;))  IDE :) When [this will we working](https://github.com/josephernest/helloworldandroidapp_withoutIDE) I'll start the encryption app :)

Comment: *LOL* another one favoring text mode, huh? Welcome :) When your app is done and does what you want, you can of course put it into an answer (with the appropriate disclosure, naturally). Looking forward to that (ping me then to add it to my lists), good luck!

Comment: Haha yeah @Izzy, I really dislike opening an IDE and having millions of menus and not knowing where to look :) Any idea for https://stackoverflow.com/q/47167769/1422096 ? :)

Comment: None at all, sorry – I'm not an Android dev.